# How do I install my AppCelerator App to my IPhone

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

I am attempting to load a small application I wrote with AppCelerator on my device. I am having quite a bit of trouble with this because of iOS target mismatches I suspect.

AppCelerator provides me two options for the target OS, 3.2 and 4.1. My Phone has firmware 4.1 on it so I selected 4.1:

Here is a picture if you want to have a look.

[image: http://www.neosavvy.com/screenshots/stackoverflow/appcelerator.png]

Note that in this image I am selecting output type of 4.1. This generates an XCode project with 4.1 as the base sdk / target sdk of 4.1.

When I launch this it generates an XCode project. Organizer contains the following devices and provisioning profiles:

Here is a picture of organizer.

[image: http://www.neosavvy.com/screenshots/stackoverflow/organizer.png]

It contains my device, with provisioning profiles, with a green dot beside the device meaning it should be a valid target.

Then when I try to run the app on my device I see the following options as available targets:

Finally here is the dropdown where you select simulators and devices.

[image: http://www.neosavvy.com/screenshots/stackoverflow/available_debug_devices.png]

Notice it simply doesn't contain my device as it did before I upgraded to the new SDK and 4.1 iOS.

I assumed I would be able to push to my iphone at this time - have tried all I know to try. Blown away all my provisioning profiles, regenerated my developer certificate, also deleted my login keychain to make sure that I started fresh there.

I am really just out of ideas to try - appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Please post a summary using words rather than linking to important information like you are doing. (Those links could disappear, which would make this question less useful for future readers)

Comment: I control that website, so I can ensure that the images stay there. I will summarize what they say though, but felt a picture was worth a thousand words. I am starting to think its a new 4.1 SDK issue and the actual functionality looks different than previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the answer was quite simple. After kludging around in XCode for hours I found (or noticed) another tab on the AppCelerator interface.

Click on Test & Package
Click on Run on Device
Fill out the details for provisioning if they aren't already (this is likely all done if you went through the level of detail on Apple Documentation that I did)
Click Install Now

Voila - the app is on your phone for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Terms and Conditions do not allow apps built outside Xcode to be installed to iOS devices.   I would think this applies to AppCelerator builds as well.

Comment: Didn't you see the news the other day? They changed the terms of their agreement. Also many AppCelerator and Monotouch applications have made it to the appstore in the past year since the change was made. You have some bad information I suspect. Also AppCelerator generates an XCode project thus why it is in the constraints of the original agreement with Apple. That change was made to prevent Flash CS5's export to IPhone feature from coming to any sort of fruition.

Comment: I have seen the news, but the restrictions Apple is easing (not lifting) still need to propagate through to Xcode.  If you target an earlier version of iOS (3.x) do you have those problems?  I would suspect not as Apple had not yet enforced that restriction.  It looks like there are some major configuration steps needed to make AppCellerator work on iOS4 (From AllCellerator):  http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/titanium-and-iphone-os-4.html